# Is it acceptable to say curse words if they are the title of a work?

Tags: slang

I'm not entirely sure this is the correct place for this question. It seems more like a question of professionalism, or more accurately, not pissing of those who dislike "curse words."  It's not strictly related to English either.

Regardless, I'm wondering if it's even considered cursing if one is citing a work whose title contains a curse word. Is it okay to talk about [Brainfuck](http://esolangs.org/wiki/brainfuck) in a academic setting, for example? Or perhaps quote something containing vulgar language?

Comment: In "polite company", you may be expected to still sensor such things.  Personally, I refuse to sensor myself in those situations, but that's part of the image I create for myself.  In an environment around children, parents may have an expectation that children are not exposed to curse words, no matter the context.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about what language is socially acceptable.  (And the social context is not even characterized).

Comment: @Nick2253 Did you mean *censor*? I suppose one could install *sensors* (electronic no doubt) among random members of the audience that would measure changes in heart rate and blood pressure every time a swear word was uttered!

Comment: @WS2 Of course I meant sensor.  Doesn't everyone install sensors in themselves in those situations?

Comment: It probably is not on topic. I've admitted that in the OP. Now, if you could direct me to where it may be on topic, or suggest how it could be reworded, instead of downvoting, that would help me tremendously.

Comment: I say it's on topic. It's about usage of English. An aspect of usage is knowing which registers to use in which situations.

Comment: "The English Language and Usage Stack Exchange is for linguists, etymologists, and (serious) English language enthusiasts. Questions on the following topics are welcomed here:

    Word choice and usage"

Answer (score 4):

If you're delivering a speech or lecture and suspect that your audience might be uncomfortable with the word, you might consider first giving them advance warning that you're about to mention a controversial term, and then say it (or write it) at least once.

After that, if you think it would make those in your audience feel better, the next time you mention it you can use an abbreviation (e.g. in this case, 'BF'). In this way, everyone will know what you're talking about because you've already used the term the initials represent, but the subsequent use of initials should minimize any possible squeamishness or discomfort among your audience.

In academia, I think there's a general expectation that intellectual rigour and thoroughness  should trump squeamishness (both in speech and in writing). However, I think it is sensible to avoid unnecessarily provoking those in your audience who feel uncomfortable with swearing or other vulgar language on a personal level. So use citations that contain such terms when they are necessary, but avoid quoting them gratuitously.

I feel that my suggested approach represents a sensible compromise between the use of potentially uncomfortable terminology and respecting other people's sensibilities.

Of course, these comments assume that the speaker or writer is not seeking to be deliberately provocative in their presentation. If they are, then all bets are off.

Comment: This does not speak about English. It offers advice about how to conduct oneself socially.

Comment: How do you feel about following a swear word with 'pardon my French'?

Comment: @WS2 - That would be fine. However, because that expression sounds rather trite to me I personally wouldn't use it unless I could give it an extra twist — for instance, if I was discussing a French film or novel.

Comment: @Drew English is not used except in society.

Comment: @jlovegren: Likewise hemorrhoid medicine. So what? Not everything used in society is appropriate fodder for EL&U.

Comment: @Drew yes, and a forum dedicated to hemorrhoid medicine should entertain questions about appropriate use of the medicine in polite company.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, if you are asking yourself if a certain word might be offensive, you will do better to avoid using it. Words which might be acceptable among schoolmates or military comrades would be offensive at a university faculty meeting.

There is a difference between *cursing*, which has to do with profane or blasphemous language, and words that are offensive because they are crude or coarse.

Whoever named it "Brain****" was limiting the utility of his work, since there are many people who will find the use of that famous f-word extremely offensive. It is not cursing, it is just a vulgarity.

Incidentally, *piss off* is another crude, vulgar term. If you want to avoid giving offense, say *anger*, *irritate*, or *offend*.

Comment: Things are changing. The expression *piss off* seems to be  transitioning in popular perception from the realm of vulgarity to that of mere colloquialism. For instance, I have heard it being used on NPR (National Public Radio) dozens of times in the past 3-4 years. It may well be a generational thing — it seems to me that under-35s, at least, tend to regard it as belonging to the common currency of normal speech. The same is true, though to a somewhat lesser degree, of *fuck*. Even my 77-year-old neighbour, a rather strait-laced woman from the Great Plains, has uttered it on occasion.

Comment: @ErikKowal, I am sure you are correct. If you used the term "pissed off" here (NW USA) in court, or at a parish council meeting, you'd get admonished or at least that look that freezes. That's exactly why I gave the warning:  it is not yet 100% inoffensive.  The f-word has more power to offend. It is not a matter of age, after all it is an ancient word, it is the context of the use that makes it taboo or unremarkable.

Comment: My use of _pissed off_ was meant to be very very dry, sarcastic, humor.